# Crouton not showing outAnimation

Tags: android, crouton

I show a [Crouton](https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/) like this:

```
    Builder b = new Builder();
    b.setBackgroundColor(R.color.mygreen);
    b.setTextAppearance(R.style.LargeTextWhite);
    Configuration.Builder configBuilder = new Configuration.Builder();
    configBuilder.setInAnimation(R.anim.slide_up).setOutAnimation(
            R.anim.shake);
    b.setConfiguration(configBuilder.build());
    Crouton.makeText(getActivity(),
            "" + e.getResult().getTotalCount() + " Treffer", b.build(),
            root).show();
```

where `root` is a `ViewGroup`;

The `inAnimation` is shown, the `outAnimation` is not, the `Crouton` just diappears. 
Anyone else has experienced this too or has an idea why it's not working?

Comment: For the record: https://github.com/keyboardsurfer/Crouton/issues/162

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I met the problem too,I check the demo's source and found that, your "root" should be :

```
<LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/croutonContainer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:orientation="vertical" />


private void showCustomViewCrouton() {
        View view = getLayoutInflater(null).inflate(R.layout.layout_crouton_custom_view, null);
        final Crouton crouton;
        final Configuration croutonConfig =  new Configuration.Builder().setDuration(Configuration.DURATION_SHORT).setInAnimation(android.R.anim.fade_in).setOutAnimation(android.R.anim.fade_out).build();
        crouton = Crouton.make(getActivity(), view, R.id.croutonContainer, croutonConfig);
        crouton.show();
      }
```

and finally fixed my problem.Hope it work for you:)

Comment: Yeah, it was the layout. I have it at the bottom of my screen and set height to wrap_content. 
Thank you!